# Using shell script to create a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux

I created a table in MYSQL using a shell script shown below in which the attributes are pre-defined.

```
dbstring="mysql -usample -psample12 -Dsampledb -h127.0.0.1 -A "

echo "CREATE TABLE info (id bigint(20) NOT NULL,email varchar(128) NOT NULL,
createddate datetime DEFAULT NULL)" >> create_table.sql


$dbstring  < create_table.sql
```

But the thing is i wanted a script that takes the number of attributes as input and takes each attribute at run-time and creates the table in my MYSQL database with those specified attributes.

Comment: And you've tried and failed with... what?

Comment: I failed with the second part in which the attributes should be taken at run-time and should be inserted in the table. Help me out with that.

Answer (score 3):

A simple example of a script which takes two parameters and juggles them into an SQL-statement to be fed to mysql. Obviously this is the idea in theory, you should adjust appropriately mysql switches and so on.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat << EOF | mysql mydatabase
CREATE TABLE info (id bigint NOT NULL, $1 varchar(128), $2 varchar(128));
EOF
```